# What is the best way to incorporate authentication in a VB6 program?

Tags: authentication, vb6

I need to figure out a way to authenticate a vb6 program I am creating, preferably all automatically.  I have a web-server with PHP that has 99% up-time, and a Windows Server that I can run a server side VB6 program on that has about a 90% up-time.  The issue I am facing though is how can I make it generate a correct key if it is a fresh install, while only allowing there to be one copy per location.  Here is what I have thought about, I was just curious if there is any easier/smarter way to do this.

Have the VB6 program generate an MD5 string that is the customers first name + customers last name + business name + customers email, then have the VB6 program save that to a key file, then finally hit a PHP script on my server (Using a hidden browser object) that stores that MD5 string (or key) into a text file.  The problem here is my PHP is very weak.

My other problem here is how can I have the vb6 program know if there are multiple copies of the same key, and then de-authenticate itself.

I can post some code that I have scratched, if anyone wants to see it.  I look forward to hearing some replies, as the deadline looms on this project, and I am utterly lost.

Comment: Please post some of the VB and PHP code you use, even if it's pseudo code... An idea of how the whole process flows would help.  Also, is the VB code trying to check for multiple copies by checking the files saved by the PHP or the VB?  From your description, they each save their own text file with the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This open source licensing framework would save some time:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/activelock/
- http://www.activelocksoftware.com/downloads.html

There are some samples and tutorials in the download section(second link).

Hope it would help you.

Wish you good luck.

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thank you for your quick response.